# Using /proc/stat for the number of processes running on the system

Tags: linux, process, proc

How does one find out the true number of processes that is running on your system? A number of articles mention using `ps` in order to count the number of processes. But recently I looked at `cat /proc/stat`, and it outputted:

```
cpu  972 0 1894 189609 236 26 490 0 0 0
cpu0 972 0 1894 189609 236 26 490 0 0 0
intr 101595 157 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 136 0 0 0 1406 0 0 14936 934 19133 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
ctxt 244344
btime 1405754990
processes 3912
procs_running 3
procs_blocked 0
softirq 122778 0 48263 439 15599 19037 0 1 0 7405 32034
```

It shows the number of processes as 3912. Using something like `ps -A --no-headers | wc -l` only shows 173 processes.

Why does `/proc/stat` show so many more processes (an increase of 3739 processes)? Who is giving the right number?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), and you'll see this for the *processes* field:

> Number of forks since boot.

So it's simply not the number you're looking for. `ps` will give you that as you already know, counting the directories with only numbers in their name under `/proc` is another approach.

Comment: Yea, another resource told me the it was the number of processes.

Answer (score 12):

Depending on whether you want to include threads or not, add the -L option to your `ps` command:

```
$ ps -A --no-headers | wc -l
359
$ ps -AL --no-headers | wc -l
967
```

Threads are not listed separately by ps by default. The point of threads is that they are 
**multiple threads of execution** inside one **process address space**.

Comment: Threads are not considered separate processes?

Comment: No - that's the point of threads. They are multiple **threads of execution** inside one process **address space**.